# How to create a condition depending on the route one is in?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an app that is divided in 3 sections, a Header, Middle and Popular

```
<>
 <Header />
 <Middle />
 <Popular />
</>
```

Header has a button that says 'Book it now' `<Link to="/booking"> <button> Book it now </button> </Link>`. When clicked, it uses React Router to switch route in the Middle component.

The 'Middle' component:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/booking">  //When 'Book it now' is clicked, this is displayed.
       <Booking />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
       <Form />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

I would like to now make that Header button disappear when the route is '/booking'. I could create state and switch it to false after the button is clicked to not display the button, but I was thinking it would be pretty handy if I could do something like this in the Header file:

```
if (route === '/booking') {
    //don't display button in Header                    (also, how would I do this?)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the React Router 'useLocation' hook, you can have access to the route at which the user is currently at:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const location = useLocation() //with no arguments

console.log(location.pathname) //e.g. '/' or '/booking'
```

The location can the be used to conditionally render anything, in any component, depending on the route the user is at

```
location.pathname === '/booking' && <button> Book it now </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `withRouter` imported from `react-router-dom`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const OtherComponent = withRouter(props => <MyComponent {...props}/>);

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { pathname } = this.props.location;
    if(pathnanme != 'booking') {
      <button>Hidden on booking</button>
    }
  }
}
```

That should be your `Booking` component:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Booking = (props) => {
  const { pathname } = props.location;

  console.log(pathname);

  return (
    <div>
      {(pathname !== 'booking' && pathname !== '/booking') ? <button>Hidden on booking</button> : null}
      <span>always shown</span>
    </div>
  );
}


export default withRouter(Booking)
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I don't understand this 'OtherComponent' and how you're getting pathname from 'MyComponent'. I am using function components so that could be why..;

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-router v5 then I like to use hooks:

```
let location = useLocation();

let isBookingPage = location.pathname.includes('booking')
```

```
<>
 {!isBookingPage && <Header />}
 <Middle />
 <Popular />
</>
```

Comment: you helped me find the answer with the useLocation hook, thanks! What I wanted was to conditionally render an element in a component and not a whole component though.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Mark the answer as accepted if it was useful.